# How to change the value in CircularProgressBar in ui kitten for react native?

Tags: react-native

const CircularBar = () => {
const [percent,setPercent]=useState(45);
return (
<ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
<Layout style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
<CircularProgressBar

```
  progress={0}
    
  />
</Layout>
</ApplicationProvider>
);
```

};

const CircularBar = () => {
const [percent,setPercent]=useState(45);
return (
<ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
<Layout style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
<CircularProgressBar

```
  progress={percent}
    
  />
</Layout>
</ApplicationProvider>
);
```

};

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.